# JQuery scripts with problems due to structural elements inserted by Wicket Framework

Tags: jquery, wicket

I have a problem using Wicket and JQuery. I am building a tree with a ul/li structure. However, Wicket inserts it's own elements which I just can't get rid of, for instance for such a structure:

```
<ul>
    <li><input type="checkbox"/></li>
    <li>
      <ul>
        <li><input type="checkbox"/></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox"/></li>
      </ul>
<ul>
```

You end up getting something like:

```
<ul>
    <span><li><input type="checkbox"/></li></span>
    <span><li>
      <wicket:panel><ul>
        <span><li><input type="checkbox"/></li></span>
        <span><li><input type="checkbox"/></li></span>
      </ul></wicket:panel>
     </span>
<ul>
```

So, the second code has some garbage which causes some issues with jquery, For instance, if I call the children() and siblings() methods on some elements of the first sample, I will get a consistent result, but with the second example, it just goes terribly complex to keep up with the "structure exceptions" (wicket:panel and span) that the Wicket framework causes.

All I want to do is to be able to set indeterminate checkbox values for which I found a nice jquery script:

http://css-tricks.com/indeterminate-checkboxes/

However, I find no way to make the script "ignore" the elements that Wicket introduces, or a way to adapt the script so that I can find the checkboxes it needs to validate.

What would be a clean approach to solve such an issue? I will be running into more, similar cases where the wicket element structure will be causing jquery scripts that have been tested on a sample page won't work anymore...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Show your markup files with the Wicket id's. 
From the output you've shown i guess that:

1. `<wicket:panel>` in the output html - to get rid of this use the procedure `setStripWicketTags(true)` http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.x/org/apache/wicket/settings/IMarkupSettings.html#setStripComments%28boolean%29
2. To get rid of the spans in the output html i guess that you are attaching wicket id's to the span element. You dont have to use the `<span>` element, you can directly add the wicket id to the `<li>` element: `<li wicket:id="blah"></li>`. Eventually on the wicket id attached to the `<span>` you can call `setRenderBodyOnly(true)`. However i dont recommend this especially if you use ajax. I dont know if this helps - i would need to see the raw markup file.

Comment: Wow, thank you for this answer. It did exactly what I was expecting, and no need to mess with working Javascript code. About the setRenderbodyOnly, I had to use it. I know I can directly use the wicket:id on my element, but since it is a list that builds itself recursively, I found no trick for getting rid of all the help elements.

Comment: Now, one small question about the setStripWicketTags. Is it a good practice to use it? I used the last option of this page for now: https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/how-to-remove-wicket-markup-from-output.html However, what would be the right approach to do it?

Comment: When i did not striped wicket Tags i had problems with IE8, so i strip them. Eventually you could try in your generated html place the wicket 1.5 XSD and maybe IE8 will catch this, but i didnt tried it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery [find](http://api.jquery.com/find/) because it is said:

> The .children() method differs from .find() in that .children() only
> travels a single level down the DOM tree while .find() can traverse
> down multiple levels to select descendant elements (grandchildren,
> etc.) as well.

You can put also some class selectors or id's on nested `li` elements for easy searching.

Comment: Yes, I am using find to select all underlying when you select the parent checkbox and that part works fine with and without the garbage. However, when you set some checkbox to indefinite, you need to check the siblings of each level and decide (bottom-up), that's where it gets complicated... I need to be able to decide wether all underlying checkboxes are selected or none...

Comment: You should use selective find, all underlying not needed. Check example in jQuery docs also.